# Nuxt 3 i18n: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split') at functionsWorker-0.7282352485608163.js:5429:32

Tags: split, internationalization, nuxt3

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')
> at functionsWorker-0.7282352485608163.js:5429:32

I keep encountering it upon deploying to cloudflare but seems to be working fine on development.

I did look for answers around but no luck!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.